# doctrine:schema:update error There is no column with name '$column' on table '$table'

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've made some changes to my doctrine Entities and need to update the database and got the following error.

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:schema:update -vvv


  [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException (30)]                   
  There is no column with name 'fleet_no' on table 'fuelData'.  


Exception trace:
 () at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/SchemaException.php:86
 Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException::columnDoesNotExist() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/Table.php:671
 Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table->getColumn() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php:711
 Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform->getPreAlterTableAlterPrimaryKeySQL() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php:639
 Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform->getPreAlterTableIndexForeignKeySQL() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php:621
 Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform->getAlterTableSQL() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/SchemaDiff.php:199
 Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaDiff->_toSql() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/SchemaDiff.php:126
 Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaDiff->toSaveSql() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/SchemaTool.php:883
 Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool->getUpdateSchemaSql() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/UpdateCommand.php:115
 Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\UpdateCommand->executeSchemaCommand() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/AbstractCommand.php:65
 Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\AbstractCommand->execute() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Command/Proxy/UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand.php:50
 Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand->execute() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:261
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:839
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:185
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:80
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:116
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/bin/console:27
```

Which is correct as such, since I have a column called 'fleetNo' but not one called 'fleet_no' in the 'fuelData' table. This was not one of the changes that I made either. 
I have searched the project directory for any other instance of 'fleet_no' but there aren't any.

Below is a copy of the fuelData entity.

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/FuelData.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fuelData")
 * 
 *
 */

class FuelData
{

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
public $fleetNo;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
public $startDate;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
public $endDate;

/**
 * Set fleetNo
 *
 * @param string $fleetNo
 *
 * @return FuelData
 */
public function setFleetNo($fleetNo)
{
    $this->fleetNo = $fleetNo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fleetNo
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFleetNo()
{
    return $this->fleetNo;
}

/**
 * Set startDate
 *
 * @param string $startDate
 *
 * @return FuelData
 */
public function setStartDate($startDate)
{
    $this->startDate = $startDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get startDate
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getStartDate()
{
    return $this->startDate;
}

/**
 * Set endDate
 *
 * @param string $endDate
 *
 * @return FuelData
 */
public function setEndDate($endDate)
{
    $this->endDate = $endDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get endDate
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEndDate()
{
    return $this->endDate;
}
}
```

The only thing that I can think of is that the column name is being converted from camelCase to underscore by something.

Is there something that I have missed or should I be looking in a different place?

Below are the relevant parts of my config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: maxdb
        connections:
            maxdb:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
            foxdb:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host2%"
                port:     "%database_port2%"
                dbname:   "%database_name2%"
                user:     "%database_user2%"
                password: "%database_password2%"
                charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        default_entity_manager: maxem
        entity_managers:
            maxem:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                connection: maxdb
                mappings:
                    AppBundle: ~
                    BWTCalendarBundle: ~
                    BWTFMBundle: ~
                    BWTHealthCheckBundle: ~
                    BWTSkytrackBundle: ~
                    BWTTelematicsBundle: ~
            foxem:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                connection: foxdb
                mappings:
                    FoxBundle: ~
```

Comment: which is the primary key for this table ?

Comment: Can you please post the Doctrine-related parts of your `app/config/config.yml`? Have you tried `app/console cache:clear` and `app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`?

Comment: @vaibhavraychura the fleetNo was the primary key.

Comment: I have also tried to add an id and make that the primary key but get the same error.

Comment: Is it working if you specify the column name : `@ORM\Column(name="fleetNo", type="string")` ?

Comment: @lxg I've added my config.yml to the post and have tried both 'cache:clear' and 'doctrine:cache:clear'

Comment: @Seb I have tried that too and get the same error

Comment: Can you try removing `@ORM\Table(name="fuelData")` ?

Comment: I guess your problem comes from your naming strategy as seen in your config file : `naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore`. It converts camelCase words to underscore. However I thought that specifying the name would work. Maybe you can try to remove/modify your naming strategy ?

Comment: Try after clearing cache. sometimes it could be headache

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    default_entity_manager: maxem
    entity_managers:
        maxem:
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
```

As you can see in your config you are using the UNDERSCORE naming strategy for the orm so that is what converts your field name.

You should do

`app/console doctrine:schema:drop`

to start off from clean then try changing the naming strategy.

In the end if you want to be sure to have the exact column name you want just add the name parameter to the colum annotation like so:

```
/**
* @Assert\NotBlank()
* @ORM\Column(type="string" name="fleetNo")
* @ORM\Id
*/
public $fleetNo;
```

Comment: Thanks to you and @Seb. i removed the naming_strategy: key, since it is not required, so that doctrine can use the simple class name and the attributes names to generate tables and columns as documented here [link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/namingstrategy.html) and it's working now

Comment: glad to hear it.happy programming!

Comment: as a alternative you can use real table field name in annotations. for example `@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="location_unique", columns={"title", "parentId"})`  instead  `@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="location_unique", columns={"title", "parent_id"})`